# Access Spring WebClient response body **BEFORE** being parsed

Tags: spring, encoding, webclient, reactive, codec

I've got a problem with an URL call **response encoding**.

So, just before Spring's **WebClient** converts the body response into an String object, as desired, I need to access the **raw** body response to parse it with the proper ***encoding***. So, just before:

```java
  <execution>.flatMap(servletResponse -> {
      Mono<String> mono = servletResponse.bodyToMono(String.class);
  }
```

I need to access the raw URL call response; I think before "*flatMap*".

So... I've been looking at "**codecs**" within Spring documentation, but... So; even for testing, I have:

- **myWriter** is an instance of: `EncoderHttpMessageWriter`.
- **myReader** is an instance of: `DecoderHttpMessageReader`.
- myWriter handles **myDecoder**, an instance of `Decoder`.
- myReader handles **myEncoder**, an instance of `Encoder`.

as per [**Spring Documentation about Codecs**](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/reference/html/web-reactive.html#webflux-codecs); and testing with both options for the WebClient Builder:

```java
myWebClientBuilder = WebClient.Builder;    // provided by Spring Context,
myWebClientBuilder = WebClient.builder();  // "by hand"
```

So, the relevant part of code looks like this (*tried even with `register` and `registerWithDefaultConfig`*):

```java
    WebClient.builder().codecs(consumer -> {
        consumer.customCodecs().register(myWriter.getEncoder());
        consumer.customCodecs().register(myWriter);
        consumer.customCodecs().register(myReader.getDecoder());
        consumer.customCodecs().register(myReader);
    })
    .build();
```

shows that the codecs load, and internal basic methods are called:

- `canDecode`
- `canEncode`
- `canRead`
- `canWrite`
- `getDecodableMimeTypes`
- `getDecoder`
- `getEncodableMimeTypes`
- `getEncoder`

but... **No one** of the `read`/`write`... `Mono<T>` / `Flux<T>` methods are used. Is there anything left for configuring a codec to properly parse the incoming response with the proper encoding?

The response is a String; a old-fashioned String, with all data-fields in a single row, that wll be parsed later, according to rules about positions and lengths of fields; nothing related with **JSON** or **Jackson**.

Is there another better way to perform this pre-action?

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: **Solved**.

The "decoder" has necessarily to implement the [HttpMessageReader](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/http/codec/HttpMessageReader.html) interface.


One good example can be reaced [here](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/12164).